# How to handle the redirected uri in ios for google sign in programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, google-oauth

I am currently doing a task in which i need to implement google sign in programmatically. I am passing the client id in the custom uri scheme and present it through svc. When i do authorization, google is not returning to my app instead it opening google.co.in page. I can get the uri in the open url method of app delegate but i don't know how to handle it and open my app instead of google.co.in page. Can someone help me to resolve it programmatically? since i should not use any predefined libraries here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Google SDK ? If so then you should've created an App on console.firebase.com , get you redirect URI from there and add it in you info.plist. It's not returning because it's not finding the redirect URI.